# Lazy repeat calculateItemHeight index is always undefined

Tags: onsen-ui

I'm using ons-lazy-repeat and I want to have variable item heights depending on the item.

For that I'm using, as described in the documentation, a delegate object with a calculateItemHeight function.

The problem is all item heights are being set to 20 because initially the *index* variable is always **undefined**. Afterwards everything seems to work correctly but everything is already rendered on the ui.

Anyone else have the same problem? I don't see what I'm doing wrong here.

This is my delegate object:

```
   $scope.TransactionDelegate = {
    configureItemScope: function(index, itemScope) {
        itemScope.item = TransactionService.allTransactions[index];
    },
    calculateItemHeight: function(index) {
        if (!index)
            return 20;

        return 60;
    },
    countItems: function() {
        return TransactionService.allTransactions.length;
    },
    destroyItemScope: function(index, scope) {
        ;
    }
  };
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a know [bug](https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/issues/678) that is now fixed and will be released in the next version.

Comment: The new version 1.3.3 of Onsen UI was released yesterday. LazyRepeat is fixed there, try it out!