# Onsen-ui ons-lazy-repeat dynamic height

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, onsen-ui

I am using ons-lazy-repeat to display a list of items. However the elements of the list have different heights.

```
$scope.MyDelegate = {
            countItems: function() {
                // Return number of items.
                return $scope.authors.length;
            },

            calculateItemHeight: function(index) {
                // Return the height of an item in pixels.
                return 200;

            },

            configureItemScope: function(index, itemScope) {
                // Initialize scope
                itemScope.author = $scope.authors[index];
            },

            destroyItemScope: function(index, itemScope) {
                // Optional method that is called when an item is unloaded.
                console.log('Destroyed item with index: ' + index);
            }
        }
```

How should implement the function calculateItemHeight to make it dynamic?

Comment: This will not work until the next version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30872723/lazy-repeat-calculateitemheight-index-is-always-undefined

And then, you have to calculate your items height manually. It depends on if they are images, text, etc.

Comment: Actually a new version that fixes this issue was just released.

Comment: Did you find out how should the dynamic height lazy-repeat be implementted?

Comment: @AndreasArgelius How we can calculate item height dynamically in calculateItemHeight ?